# Strongly typed resources from database

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have created my own DBResourceProvider which gets texts from a database in a given language.
I can set a label problematically by writing

```
Label1.Text = Text.Slogan;
```

In the webpage itself I can write

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:MyDbResource, Slogan %>"></asp:Label>
```

I am trying to figure out a way that I can have that last line of code strongly typed. Is that even possible?

**UPDATE:**

I generate this code to access the resources:

```
 public static String Slogan { get{return getText("Slogan") ;} }
```

And this is my getText method:

```
public static string getText(string key)
{
    return HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", key).ToString();   
}
```

*If you think I included to little of my code here, give me a comment and I'll bring more code to the table!*

Comment: I don't think that is possible, except if you compile your resource access class based on the db.

Comment: MyKeys is generated from the database and compiled - I use a TT file for this.

Comment: @Stian Why don't you generate code to access the resource itself via the TT template rather than just the key?

Comment: I have, I just tried to hold this question as general as possible, but I see that I might have failed in that. I'll update my question with some more code in a few seconds!

Comment: @Stian Now I'm confused - the first line of code implies `Text.Slogan` returns the resource key; your last bit of code shows it returning the resource text.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I tried to make things simple but ended up confusing everybody - hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .aspx file just write:

```
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
    Our slogan is: <%= Text.Slogan %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jeez.. I had the solution the whole time, it was only that I could not use it nested in a label like that. Thanks!